# .Net Open Telemetry metrics don't show up in Prometheus

Tags: c#, .net, prometheus, metrics, open-telemetry

I'm trying to configure metrics using Open Telemetry Protocol in my .Net 6.0 API project and although these metrics are being picked up by the OTLP receiver, they don't show up in the Prometheus exporter. The strange thing is that I can still see other traces and metrics from the OTLP target in Prometheus, it is only the metrics coming from my application that don't make it Prometheus (but, again, they do make it to the OTLP).

My setup looks like this:

Starup.cs

```
            services.AddOpenTelemetryMetrics(opts => opts
                .SetResourceBuilder(ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault().AddService("otel-collector"))
                .AddMeter(metrics.MetricName)
                .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
                .AddConsoleExporter()
                .AddOtlpExporter()
            );
```

Metrics instrumentation class

```
    public class OtelMetrics
    {
        private Counter<int> MoveToLoadPositionCounter { get; }
        private Counter<int> MoveToSetupPositionCounter { get; }        
        private Histogram<double> MoveToPositionDelayHistogram { get; }
        public string MetricName { get; }

        public OtelMetrics(string meterName = "RealTimeChannelMeter")
        {
            var meter = new Meter(meterName);
            MetricName = meterName;

            MoveToLoadPositionCounter = meter.CreateCounter<int>("move_to_load", "Movement");
            MoveToSetupPositionCounter = meter.CreateCounter<int>("move_to_setup", "Movement");
            MoveToPositionDelayHistogram = meter.CreateHistogram<double>("move_to_position_delay", "Ms", "Move to position latency.");
        }
        
        public void AddToMoveToLoad() => MoveToLoadPositionCounter.Add(1);
        public void AddToMoveToSetup() => MoveToSetupPositionCounter.Add(1);
        public void MoveToPositionDelay(double delayMs) => MoveToPositionDelayHistogram.Record(delayMs);

    }
```

Triggering metrics:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("Load")]
        [ApiConventionMethod(typeof(DefaultApiConventions), nameof(DefaultApiConventions.Post))]
        public async Task<ActionResult<MoveToPositionResponse>> LoadAsync(MoveToPositionRequest request)
        {
            _metrics.AddToMoveToLoad();

            var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            await Task.Delay(5000);
            watch.Stop();

            _metrics.MoveToPositionDelay(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            return CreateActionResult(MovementResult.SUCCESS);
        }
```

OTLP configuration file:

```
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      http:

exporters:
  prometheus:
    endpoint: "0.0.0.0:8888"

processors:
  batch:

extensions:
  health_check:

service:
  extensions: [health_check]
  pipelines:
    metrics:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [prometheus]
```

Running OTLP as Docker container:

```
docker run -d -p 8888:8888 -p 8889:8889 -p 13133:13133 -p 4317:4317 -p 4318:4318 -v ./config.yaml:/etc/otel-collector-config.yamll otel/opentelemetry-collector:0.60.0
```

Prometheus configuration file:

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'RealTimeChannelMeter'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['host.docker.internal:8889']
      - targets: ['host.docker.internal:8888']
```

Prometheus Dockerfile:

```
FROM prom/prometheus:v2.38.0

ADD prometheus.yml /etc/prometheus/
```

Running Prometheus as Docker container:

```
docker build -t prometheus2 . 
docker run -d -p 9000:9000 prometheus2
```

The metrics that I see in the explorer are the following

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBEvh.png)

When I check the logs inside the OTLP container I can see that for instance one of the metrics that makes it to Prometheus looks like this:

```
Resource SchemaURL: 
Resource attributes:
     -> service.name: STRING(otel-collector)
     -> service.instance.id: STRING(0.0.0.0:8888)
     -> net.host.port: STRING(8888)
     -> http.scheme: STRING(http)
ScopeMetrics #0
ScopeMetrics SchemaURL: 
InstrumentationScope  
Metric #0
Descriptor:
     -> Name: otelcol_exporter_enqueue_failed_metric_points
     -> Description: Number of metric points failed to be added to the sending queue.
     -> Unit: 
     -> DataType: Sum
     -> IsMonotonic: true
     -> AggregationTemporality: AGGREGATION_TEMPORALITY_CUMULATIVE
NumberDataPoints #0
Data point attributes:
     -> exporter: STRING(logging)
     -> service_instance_id: STRING(32709c55-4140-4bb7-98c3-94a09b557f4c)
     -> service_version: STRING(0.60.0)
StartTimestamp: 2023-02-23 16:24:28.395 +0000 UTC
Timestamp: 2023-02-23 16:24:28.395 +0000 UTC
Value: 0.000000
```

On the other side one of the metrics coming from my application in the OTLP container but that doesn't show in Prometheus looks like this:

```
Resource SchemaURL: 
Resource attributes:
     -> service.name: STRING(otel-collector)
     -> service.instance.id: STRING(1e10dd35-13c6-4d1d-9f42-4a82611924da)
ScopeMetrics #0
ScopeMetrics SchemaURL: 
InstrumentationScope RealTimeChannelMeter 
Metric #0
Descriptor:
     -> Name: move-to-load
     -> Description: 
     -> Unit: Movement
     -> DataType: Sum
     -> IsMonotonic: true
     -> AggregationTemporality: AGGREGATION_TEMPORALITY_CUMULATIVE
NumberDataPoints #0
StartTimestamp: 2023-02-23 16:07:04.4076488 +0000 UTC
Timestamp: 2023-02-23 16:08:04.3291068 +0000 UTC
Value: 2
```

My assumption is that it has to do something with
     -> net.host.port: STRING(8888)
     -> http.scheme: STRING(http)
since that's the only difference that I can notice between the cases, but I'm not sure how to configure that in my .Net application. If however that is not the case, can I get some insights on what am I doing wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Drive-by comment, familiar with Prometheus, unfamiliar with Open Telemetry although used OpenCensus. I suspect (!?) that you can't proxy metrics through the Collector. Your configuration is working in-as-much as the Collector is exporting its own metrics to your Prometheus instance but your app metrics aren't/can't(?) be proxied. Generally (!) Prometheus metrics exporters publish metrics on an in-app HTTP endpoint (i.e. directly) as [Prometheus](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/net/exporters/#prometheus)

Comment: >do something with      -> net.host.port: STRING(8888) 
Those are just resource attributes the collector adds to its own metrics, so that's not related. Did you try reaching to the endpoint on the collector to see if you see your metrics there? `http://localhost:8888`? If they aren't there then you know it's a problem in the collector.